# Event logging for auditing with replay

Tags: postgresql, logging, event-sourcing

I need to implement an auditing log for GDPR compliance so that we have a record of every consent given or revoked (an event) per user of our system. It has to store how & when it happened alongside things like what the wording of the consent actually was at the time.

So that we can recover from a backup restore, this log will be stored separately from our main DB. We will then need to be able to update the state of the user consent so that it accurately reflects the event log (i.e. the last known value (true/false) of each consent question per user)

I could simply do this using a second postgres instance (our main DB is postgres) with a single table to store the information and then some simple application code to log each event as well as update the main DB. There could also be some simple application logic to find the last known states of each consent from the event log and update the master DB.

To me it seems like a bit of overkill using postgres to store this info? though adding a new technology to store this also seems overkill. Are there any technologies that are more suitable for this sort of thing? It sounds a lot like Event Sourcing to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already running postgres, it doesn't seem like overkill, given that it needs to be online and queryable. Something like kafka is often a natural fit for this kind of problem, but that's even more overkill.

This bears a passing resemblance to event sourcing, but on a really small scale.  Event sourcing usually means that *all* your data is expressed in terms of events, and replayed from beginning to end to materialize the current state.

Could you elaborate on this?:

> So that we can recover from a backup restore, this log will be stored separately from our main DB.

Doesn't your main database recover from a backup / restore?

Comment: I guess I mean if the preference was set between the time of the last DB backup and the DB corruption. OR (more likely) if restoring an old DB backup for some other purpose but a user had invoked their "right to be forgotten" or "right of restriction" — meaning that whatever data analysis was happening on the restored DB would have to adhere to the user's request. Saying that, we could restore from a backup and then update those things against the live DB event table.

Comment: I guess what you're saying is that this data is more important to you than all your other data, so much so that you'd be willing to take on additional operational expense to make sure you never lose it. What is more reliable than your existing postgres database? A second pg db doesn't seem any better unless the simple nature of the data makes it easier to backup/restore. A distributed system like kafka might be more reliable, but only if you can afford the effort of operating it correctly.